# How to remove an error in argument parsing

Tags: python, argparse

When I try to parse an argument before processing an image for masking, I'm getting the below seen error. Can someone please help me with the resolution?

> usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [-h] -i IMAGE
>   ipykernel_launcher.py: error: the following arguments are required: -i/--image
>   
> An exception has occurred, use %tb to see the full traceback."

[image]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question should include the actual code instead of an image of code. Please take a look how to create a [minimal,reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and use the ["edit" link](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62460427/edit) under the question to update it with the your example.

Answer (score 1):

This error means, that you did neither specify `-i` nor `--image` as parameters when calling the program. 
Let's say your program is called `something.py` try calling it like:

```
python something.py --image "some_picture.png"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you're running the code in python idle, which Is not supposed to be the case.
You're supposed to run it in your command prompt[cmd]. The code is for the purpose of command line interface[CLI].

So to do that on windows you have to first specify the location of the python file in you want to run.

```
cd file_path
python something.py --images examples
```

You do all that in your cmd and it should work.
Note: examples is a folder containing all images